# How to interpret impute indicators in a regression model?

Tags: regression, data-imputation, categorical-encoding

Suppose I have imputed a variable in my data and that I’ve created an ‘imputed’ indicator/dummy variable, where 1 denotes that the value has been imputed and 0 if the value was already present in my dataset.

Next, I run a regression with the imputed variable in my model, including the indicator/dummy variable. Now, what does the significance (and coefficient) of this indicator/dummy mean? 
 From what I could find, it only denotes that, if it’s significant, whether or not the data was missing at random (Source: https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats2/l12.pdf)

Comment: You might find it fruitful first to contemplate the interpretation of *any* such indicator, and then to translate that interpretation into your situation.